# pacman and powerpill not working

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Both pacman and powerpill don't seem to be working on my Arch installation. I'm sure my Internet connection is working. The download just starts in powerpill but speed remains zero. In pacman, there's an error saying 'No file address found'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to give a specific answer without a more detailed error description, however, it does sound like your mirrorlist file is out of date or misconfigured in some way.

I wrote a quick script to update the file without the use of pacman:

```
#!/bin/bash

MIRRORS_URL="http://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/?country=United+States&protocol=ftp&protocol=http&ip_version=4"
MIRRORS_FILE=/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

wget -O $MIRRORS_FILE.rank $MIRRORS_URL
sed -i 's/^#//' $MIRRORS_FILE.rank
rankmirrors -n 6 $MIRRORS_FILE.rank > $MIRRORS_FILE
```

In a nutshell, that script will pull an updated list of mirrors, rank them in order of speed and save the list in your mirrorlist file.

The given url assumes you want mirrors in the United States, using ftp or http, and only IPv4. You can modify that by going to http://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist and customizing it as you see fit.

Once the script completes, then run

```
sudo pacman -Syy
```

and hopefully it works!

**Edit:**

By the way, I forgot to mention that powerpill [has been deprecated](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=115660).

Comment: @jonyamo- Thanks, but my problem here was already solved some time back(I'm sorry for keeping the question open). Since I found your answer quite comprehensive, I hope other people having similar problems will find your answer useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Update your mirrorlist file `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`. And run `pacman -Sy` before trying to install a package. You can use kernel.org's mirrors:

```
Server = ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

Comment: explaining how to update the mirrorlist if pacman is broken would make this even better.

Comment: updating it? the only thing you should do is adding that line to "/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.conf". After you do that, you can update "pacman-mirrorlist" package with "pacman -Sy pacman-mirrorlist".

Comment: Except that mirrors.kernel.org is currently down.. so use a different mirror.